# OnClick update all Lists together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(".button").on('click', function(){
  $(".updateCase").removeClass("hidden");
  var thisBtn = $(this);
  //$(this).parent( "li" ).find("h1").toggleClass( "red" );
  var currentText = thisBtn.parent( "li" ).find(".textdata").text();
  thisBtn.parent( "li" ).find("h1").replaceWith('<input name="test" class="editedText" type="text" value="' + currentText + '">');
  thisBtn.addClass("hidden");  
  $(".updateCase").on('click', function(){
  var inputT = $(".editedText");
    var editedTextValue = $(".editedText").val();
    $(".button").removeClass("hidden");
    $(".updateCase").addClass("hidden");
    var save = function(){
    var $p = $($input.data()["tagName"]).text( inputT.val() ).addClass(inputT.attr("class"));
    inputT.replaceWith( $p );
  };
      inputT.one('blur', save).focus();
      $(".updateCase").parent( ".container" ).find("input").replaceWith('<h1  class="textdata">' + editedTextValue + ' </h1>');
  })

})
```

```css
.red{
  color: pink;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <li>
    <button class="button btn btn-warning pull-right">clicked</button>
    <h1 class="textdata">First</h1>
  </li>
   <li>
    <button class="button btn btn-warning pull-right">clicked</button>
    <h1 class="textdata">Second</h1>
  </li>
   <li>
    <button class="button btn btn-warning pull-right">clicked</button>
    <h1 class="textdata">Third</h1>
  </li>
   <li>
    <button class="button btn btn-warning pull-right">clicked</button>
    <h1 class="textdata">Fourth</h1>
  </li>
  <hr>
  <button class="updateCase btn btn-success hidden">
  Update
  </button>
</div>
```

Hi there,

I was trying to convert the `<h1>` to `<input>` and edit it, when I click on update `Button` am not able to save all properly, it is saving all as one value. But if I save individually, it is saving properly, but all together am not able to save. the following is the code which I tried.

The following is the jsFiddle link:
[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/j2n1yz5g/)

Comment: please elaborate on the title what exactly do you want

Comment: what `<p>` ? I don't see any `p` element in your HTML...

Comment: I don't see any `<p>` in your HTML

Comment: sorry, they are in `H1` tags

Comment: @vsync He puts 4 `<p>` elements on the left side of the screen, and if the user clicks the button to the right, it changes that `<p>` to an `<input>` so the user can edit the text. His issue is, when clicking the "Update" button, it copies 1 value to all 4 `<p>` boxes, rather than copying each individual value.

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain it looks like you just need a way to mark each `<p>` to know which one you're referring to, either with an "active" class or with an ID.  If no one else can mock up a solution first, I'll try to type one up a little later.

Comment: @vsync yes you are correct, but am unable to do it.

Comment: @freginold, I tried allot but dint find a solution of my level.

Comment: @freginold - **There are no** `p` elements anywhere in the HTML he posted, sorry.

Comment: @vsync oops, meant the `h1` elements. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this it's work :**

```js
 $(".button").on('click', function () {

            $(".updateCase").removeClass("hidden");
            var thisBtn = $(this);
            //$(this).parent( "li" ).find("h1").toggleClass( "red" );
            var currentText = thisBtn.parent("li").find(".textdata").text();
            thisBtn.parent("li").find("h1").replaceWith('<input name="test" class="editedText" type="text" value="' + currentText + '">');
            thisBtn.addClass("hidden");

            $(".updateCase").on('click', function () {

                $(".editedText").each(function () {
                    var inputT = $(this);
                    var editedTextValue = $(this).val();

                    var save = function () {
                        var $p = $($input.data()["tagName"]).text(inputT.val()).addClass(inputT.attr("class"));
                        inputT.replaceWith($p);
                    };

                    inputT.one('blur', save).focus();

                    $(this).replaceWith('<h1  class="textdata">' + editedTextValue + ' </h1>');
                });

                $(".button").removeClass("hidden");
                $(".updateCase").addClass("hidden");

            })
        })
```

```css
.red{
  color: pink;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <li>
    <button class="button btn btn-warning pull-right">clicked</button>
    <h1 class="textdata">First</h1>
  </li>
   <li>
    <button class="button btn btn-warning pull-right">clicked</button>
    <h1 class="textdata">Second</h1>
  </li>
   <li>
    <button class="button btn btn-warning pull-right">clicked</button>
    <h1 class="textdata">Third</h1>
  </li>
   <li>
    <button class="button btn btn-warning pull-right">clicked</button>
    <h1 class="textdata">Fourth</h1>
  </li>
  <hr>
  <button class="updateCase btn btn-success hidden">
  Update
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain, what mistake I did ?

Comment: you can not access all input field like `var inputT = $(".editedText"); var editedTextValue = $(".editedText").val();`
You need to use `each loop` with common class of all input

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following:
**$($input.data()["tagName"]) to  $(":input")**

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputT = $(".editedText");
```

this will return an array of  element so you have to loop through it. so you can fetch the value of an individual  element like,

```
for(var i = 0; i<inputT.length; i++){
var editedTextValue = inputT[i];
console.log(editedTextValue.value);
}
```

may it will help you to solve your problem.